# PHP + MYSQL select row and display it

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

so I have the code below, it works perfectly but I want to make it like so:

I have the latest 6 products from my MYSQL database that displays on page

I have the details on a modal clickable thing

When I click for example product number 5, to show the details from MYSQL database for product 5, product number 4, details from MYSQL database for product 4 and so on.

I tried some things but couldn't make it done, here is the code:

```
<?php
                      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 6
");
                      $stmt->execute([]);
                      

                      while($res=$stmt->fetch()) {

                        echo  '      
                <div class="user-block block" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px;">
                        <button class="btnnn" ><strong style="font-weight: 200; width: 100%;">PRODUSE</strong></button><br><br>
                    <div>
                    <strong style="font-weight: 200">Produs:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;">'.htmlspecialchars($res['produs']).'</strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Pret:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;">'.htmlspecialchars($res['price']).'€</strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Autor:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;">'.htmlspecialchars($res['autor']).'</strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Data:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;">'.htmlspecialchars($res['data']).'</strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Detalii:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test2">Click</a></strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Video/Poze:</strong><strong style="font-weight: 200;"><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($res['poze']).'" style="color: aqua; margin-left: 3px;">Click</a></strong><Br>
<strong style="font-weight: 200">Expira in:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;">'.htmlspecialchars($res['dayss']).' zile</strong>
</div></div>
';
                      }

                  ?>
```

MODAL

```
       <div class="modal" id="test2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Detalii</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
     
      <?php
                      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT detalii 
  FROM products 
 ORDER 
   BY id DESC LIMIT 1
");
                      $stmt->execute([]);
                      

                      while($res=$stmt->fetch()) {

                        echo  '      
      <div class="modal-body">
      '.htmlspecialchars($res['detalii']).'
      </div>';
    }

?>
```

Comment: where's the relation between the two codes?

Comment: <strong style="font-weight: 200">Detalii:</strong> <strong style="font-weight: 200;"><a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test2">Click</a></strong><Br>

Comment: data-target = the modal code.

Comment: I can see that. Sorry, my question was referring to the query, I didn't see the relation between product and product details. your detail query needs filter based on the product.